# openstack services not showing up

Tags: openstack, cinder

Openstack(devstack) just installed on ubuntu 20.04.3 (4cpu, 8Gb), with local.conf by stack.sh

> [[local|localrc]]
>  ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret
> DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
>
> RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
> SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
> HOST_IP=192.168.31.200

And it looks like works fine, but "systemctl -t service" don't showing cinder services (cinder-scheduler, cinder-volume) and obviously some others:

[systemctl -t service output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkYiU.png)

[cinder service-list ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNGbb.png)

so, wt.. ?

Answer (score 1):

All services named `devstack@...` are OpenStack services. Specifically, Cinder's services are named `c-api`, `c-sch` and `c-vol`.

See also https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/systemd.html.